# Binding Repeater value on the basis of Radiboutton through label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater in which there is a Row which brings a value of Salary from a table. And there is a condition:

1)When user adds the salary value in a textbox, there are two radio buttons, YES and NO,
I want, whenever user selects the yes option, the salary value should be displayed in the repeater.
Please see the code for the Repeater and Textbox, Radiobuttons:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_Jobs" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <h3 class="parag"><%# Eval("Position") %> - <%#Eval("Location") %></h3>
            <div>
                <table class="tab_table">
                    <tr class="a12">
                    <td  style="font-weight:600;">Salary Range</td>
                    <%--<td><%#Eval("SalaryRange") %> lakhs per annum</td>--%>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblSalary" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SalaryRange") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <div class="btnDropbox"><a href='CareerApply.aspx?jobid=<%#Eval("JobId") %>'><b>Apply</b></a></div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Textbox and Radiobutton code:-

```
<td>
    <asp:TextBox CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="txtSalaryRange" runat="server">    
    </asp:TextBox><span style="color: #CF060D;">lakhs per annum</span>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqSalaryRange" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSalaryRange" ErrorMessage="Please enter salary" SetFocusOnError="true"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  CssClass="error_msg" ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtSalaryRange" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Salary" ValidationExpression="^(\d{1,3})(.\d{1,2})?$">    
    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbButtonYes" runat="server" Text="Show" GroupName="salary" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbButtonNo" runat="server" Text="Not Show" GroupName="salary" />
</td>
```

Note: The textbox of salary and Repeater is two different page.  What should I do to show in repeater when the radiobutton is selected YES.

I tried with label on repeater and bringing value through querystring but couldn't achieved it. 
Please help.

Comment: Can you please post your code to bind repeater?

Comment: The repeater is binded on dropdown list selecting value. please see the JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/pY5H3/

Comment: On item data bound event of repeater find "lblSalary" & hide if in querystring value is "No"

Comment: I am unable to find lblSalary, because that ID is coming from another page. Could you please let me know how to bring that ID in the repeater ?? Please